# iOS Linked-in Once Authenticated : while calling Url of user Profile again ask for authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiwebview, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn API for LinkedIn Integration. I am able to post Status Update. I want to show user profile in UIWebView in iOS for that I am getting user public URL when i fetched user profile.

If I am going to open this url in WebView then its redirecting to LinkedIn Login page and after filling Credential I can see user Profile.

I want to open User Profile without entering Credential,Again

I also tried by appending the

`URL&accesstoken="tokenIdReturned by Application";`

But I am sill not able to open the User Profile directly. What am I missing?